# How to find a point at a certain distance to other points on the same line

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Assuming the points A(x1,y1) and B(x2,y2) and distances between AB (d1) and AC (d2) are known. How can I find the point C(xp,yp)?

[image: points on line]

Actually it has a trivial solution, writing the distance equation 2 times between AB and AC and also getting the slope for the line AB, and substituting it back gives the solution. However, it is also possible for my case that the slope can be infinity and also I do not want to get two possible answers due to squareroot operation and I need to derive an equation that is valid for all cases. How can one achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: One issue can't be avoided: having two solutions. You will always have two solutions, except if you state on top of what you already write that you want $C$ to be on the same side that $B$ on or the opposite side.

Comment: Have you studied any linear algebra? Looking at this problem from the perspective of vectors would be advantageous.

Comment: I want the point C, always on the opposite direction of the vector from point A to point B. So I always want the point C on the opposite side of the B. In addition, any vector operations to do this would also be appreciated, since I am trying to do this as a part of my algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x_p=x_1\pm \dfrac{d_2}{d_1}(x_2-x_1)$

and

$y_p=y_1\pm \dfrac{d_2}{d_1}(y_2-y_1)$

Of course you need to take the same sign for the two equations. You have only $2$ solutions, not $4$.

EDIT: if you want the opposite side, you have to choose the $-$ sign.

EDIT2: I was not awake... There is no $\sqrt{}$...

Comment: Would this also be valid in case the requirements are as in my comment above?

define p=d2/(d1+d2), 
xp=(x1-p*x2)/(1-p), 
yp=(y1-p*y2)/(1-p),

Comment: I don't understand your new definition of $p$ in your comment... It is not the same problem...

Comment: What I tried is assuming point C as start of the line segment, and point B as end. P is the ratio of the distance of AC to the CB which is d2/(d1+d2). Then (xp,yp)=p*((x2,y2)-(xp,yp)). I reorganized this to solve for (xp,yp), thus as p varies between 0 and 1, I can get (xp,yp)

Comment: Oh, okay, same thing as I described above then. I was trying to avoid square roots, which didn't make sense. Thanks. This seems the valid answer then.